# How can I read from a socket repeatedly?

Tags: c#, sockets

To start I am coding in C#. I am writing data of varying sizes to a device through a socket. After writing the data I want to read from the socket because the device will write back an error code/completion message once it has finished processing all of the data. Currently I have something like this:

```
byte[] resultErrorCode = new byte[1];
resultErrorCode[0] = 255;

while (resultErrorCode[0] == 255)
{
    try
    {
        ReadFromSocket(ref resultErrorCode);
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(ErrorList[resultErrorCode[0] - 48]);
```

I use `ReadFromSocket` in other places, so I know that it is working correctly. What ends up happening is that the port I am connecting from (on my machine) changes to random ports. I think that this causes the firmware on the other side to have a bad connection. So when I write data on the other side, it tries to write data to the original port that I connected through, but after trying to read several times, the connection port changes on my side.

How can I read from the socket continuously until I receive a completion command? If I know that something is wrong with the loop because for my smallest test file it takes 1 min and 13 seconds pretty consistently. I have tested the code by removing the loop and putting the code to sleep for 1 min and 15 seconds. When it resumes, it successfully reads the completion command that I am expecting. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: this looks like really basic synchronous code. you should look into asynchronous event driven sockets using i/o completion ports...or another c# library that handles sockets with events.

Comment: @Timmerz - I will look into it more, but I have already looked at a few things with asynchronous sockets. I don't understand how that would help me in this situation. I am not very familiar with sockets, this is pretty much my first endeavor with them.

Comment: synchronous sockets is a horrible idea. so, firstly you should be using event based sockets. secondly, there is usually a protocol implemented on top of the sockets, which tells things like, how many bytes to read, etc...this is like http, etc. I don't understand the random ports stuff...I would think you would just keep the connection open til all communication is finished. otherwise you should be accepting connections from the device, but that should all be understood as part of the protocol, and then in that case you have to use a listener as well.

Comment: @Timmerz - Thank you. The original coder set it up, and I see now that he does use synchronous writing/connecting/reading at every point. I will go through and try to fix it without breaking anything.

Comment: Synchronous sockets a horrible idea? There are situations when there's nothing wrong with them, just not on the UI thread (if any). About the random ports - if a client connects to a server, you specify the port the server is listening to. Unless you specify a client port as well, a "random" port will be used, but usually this should not be a problem. As long as a connection remains open, no ports change.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - I think that since I repeatedly try to read from the connection and since the data is still being delt with on the other device, nothing is read. The code interprets this as a SocketException (hence why I have it in a try catch embedded in the loop) and to resolve it, a new connection is opened. That is what I think is happening...but I don't know for sure. I print out the start port and ip and end port and ip every time i try to read, and the start port changes for every read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should have is a separate thread which will act like a driver of your external hardware. This thread will receive all data, parse it and transmit the appropriate messages to the rest of your application. This portion of code will give you an idea of how receive and parse data from your hardware.

```
  public void ContinuousReceive(){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    bool terminationCodeReceived = false;
    while(!terminationCodeReceived){
      try{
          if(server.Receive(buffer)>0){
             // We got something
             // Parse the received data and check if the termination code
             // is received or not
          }
      }catch (SocketException e){
          Console.WriteLine("Oops! Something bad happened:" + e.Message);
      }
    }
  }
```

**Notes:**

1. If you want to open a specific port on your machine (some external hardware are configured to talk to a predefined port) then you should specify that when you create your socket
2. Never close your socket until you want to stop your application or the external hardware API requires that. Keeping your socket open will resolve the random port change
3. using `Thread.Sleep` when dealing with external hardware is not a good idea. When possible, you should either use events (in case of RS232 connections) or blocking calls on separate threads as it is the case in the code above.

Comment: This worked very well. Thank you. I guess the original coders had abstracted more than I thought with their ReadFromSocket function. Calling the Socket class's Receive method continuously seemed to do the trick. Thanks again. Also, I only used the Thread.Sleep as a test to see if a single read would work as opposed to continuously polling, but thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I tried to +1, but I can't until I have a reputation above 15.

Comment: Sure no problem :) You can always come back :)