# Web Sockets misbehave when sending data very fast

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, websocket

I am new to WebSockets so I am sorry if it is due to my fault but when I send data from WebSocket (in chrome) to a server (C#, TCPListener) in a while loop (just to test) the data do not arrive the server properly. It's first byte is usually gone and sometimes keys also get mixed between two messages. This results in my server crashing. This never happens when data is sent irregularly or not super fast one after another.

Here is the server Receiver code:

```
#region Receiver

    public class Receiver
    {
        private const int DEFAULT_DATA_LIMIT = 256; // Bytes

        private const int HEADER_LENGTH = 2;
        private const int KEYS_LENGTH = 4;

        private const int SHORT_BYTES = 2;
        private const int LONG_BYTES = 8;

        private const int SHORT_DATA = 126;
        private const int LONG_DATA = 127;

        private readonly Socket TargetSocket;

        private readonly object DataLock = new object();
        private readonly object amountOfDataReceivedLock = new object();
        private readonly object RecevingLock = new object();
        private readonly object CompletingRecieveLock = new object();

        private bool receiving;

        private int _amoutOfDataReceived;
        private byte[] Data;

        private int amountOfDataReceived
        {
            get
            {
                lock(amountOfDataReceivedLock)
                    return _amoutOfDataReceived;
            }
            set
            {
                lock(amountOfDataReceivedLock)
                    _amoutOfDataReceived = value;
            }
        }

        public int Capacity
        {
            get
            {
                return Data.Length;
            }
        }

        public int FreeSpace
        {
            get
            {
                return Capacity - amountOfDataReceived;
            }
        }

        public bool ReceivingData
        {
            get
            {
                return receiving;
            }
        }

        public bool ChunkReady
        {
            get
            {
                int wholeChunkLength = WholeChunkLength();

                if(wholeChunkLength == -1)
                    return false;

                return WholeChunkLength() <= amountOfDataReceived;
            }
        }

        public Receiver(Socket socket, int dataLimit)
        {
            this.TargetSocket = socket;
            Data = new byte[dataLimit];
        }

        public Receiver(Socket socket) : this(socket, DEFAULT_DATA_LIMIT) { }

        private int ChunkDataLength()
        {
            lock(DataLock)
            {
                lock(amountOfDataReceivedLock)
                {
                    if(amountOfDataReceived < 1)
                        return -1;

                    int lengthInfoIndex = HEADER_LENGTH - 1;

                    if(amountOfDataReceived < lengthInfoIndex + 1)
                        return -1;

                    int rawLength = Data[lengthInfoIndex] -128;

                    int bytesRequiredToGetLength = 0;

                    if(rawLength == SHORT_DATA)
                        bytesRequiredToGetLength = SHORT_BYTES;
                    else if(rawLength == LONG_DATA)
                        bytesRequiredToGetLength = LONG_BYTES;
                    else
                        return rawLength;

                    if(amountOfDataReceived < lengthInfoIndex + 1 + bytesRequiredToGetLength)
                        return -1;

                    return Utilities.ToInt32(Data, lengthInfoIndex + 1, bytesRequiredToGetLength);
                }
            }
        }

        private int WholeChunkLength()
        {
            int dataLength = ChunkDataLength();
            int lengthInfoLength = dataLength < SHORT_DATA ? 0 : dataLength < short.MaxValue ? SHORT_BYTES : LONG_BYTES;

            if(dataLength == -1)
                return -1;

            return HEADER_LENGTH + lengthInfoLength + KEYS_LENGTH + dataLength;
        }

        private void ReceiveDataInternal(int dataToReceiveLength)
        {
            if(dataToReceiveLength == 0)
                return;

            lock(RecevingLock)
            {
                if(receiving)
                    return;

                receiving = true;
            }

            if(dataToReceiveLength > FreeSpace)
                dataToReceiveLength = FreeSpace;

            TargetSocket.BeginReceive(Data, amountOfDataReceived, dataToReceiveLength, SocketFlags.None, result =>
            {
                OnRecevingComplete(result, dataToReceiveLength);
            }, null);

        }

        private void OnRecevingComplete(System.IAsyncResult result, int receivedDataLength)
        {
            lock(CompletingRecieveLock) // This is not needed really
            {
                TargetSocket.EndReceive(result);
                this.amountOfDataReceived += receivedDataLength;
                receiving = false;
            }
        }

        public void ReceiveData()
        {
            ReceiveDataInternal(TargetSocket.Available);
        }

        public byte[] GetChunk()
        {
            lock(DataLock)
            {
                lock(amountOfDataReceivedLock)
                {
                    int chunkLength = WholeChunkLength();

                    if(chunkLength == -1 || chunkLength > amountOfDataReceived)
                        return null;
                     //                            throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Chunk is yet not ready!");

                    byte[] chunk = new byte[chunkLength];

                    for(int i = 0; i < chunkLength; i++)
                        chunk[i] = Data[i];

                    ArrayUtilities<byte>.ShiftArrayLeft(Data, chunkLength, amountOfDataReceived);
                    amountOfDataReceived -= chunkLength;

                    return chunk;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    #endregion
```

Here is the function calling the Receiver class

```
private void Update()
    {
        if(!running)
            return;

        for(int i = 0; i < clients.TotalClients; i++)
        {
            if(!clients[i].IsReady)
                continue;

            var recievier = clients[i].GetReciever();

            if(recievier.recievier.FreeSpace > 0 && clients[i].DataAvaliable && !recievier.Receiving)
                recievier.ReceiveData();

            if(recievier.ChunkReady)
            {
                var data = recievier.GetChunk();

                Utilities.WSFormatter.DecodeMessage(data);

                int SI = Utilities.WSFormatter.MessageStartIndex(data);

                System.Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, SI, data.Length - SI));
            }

        }
    }
```

The function itself is called by something like this (on a new thread, other than the default one):

```
while (true)
{
    Update();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
}
```

and here is the WebSocket code:

```
        Engine.Loader.loadEngine(function() {

        var client = new Engine.Client("ws:192.168.1.105:8080");
        var connected = false;

        client.addConnectListener(function()
        {
            connected = true;
            console.log("Connection successful!");              
        });

        client.addRecieveListener(function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        });

        var gl = new Engine.GameLoop(new Engine.Renderer(), new Engine.Input(), client);
        gl.start();

        var i = 0;

        gl.addEventListener("UPDATE", function()
        {
            /*The code that works*/

            if(connected)
                client.sendString("" + i++);

            /*The code that causes problems*/

            var j = 10;

            while(connected && j-- > 0)
                client.sendString("" + i++);

        });

    });
```

EDIT: The UPDATE event is called by window.requestAnimationFrame

EDIT: The answer I posted earlier also failed. Turns out it only works when the data[] gets filled before the error occurs. So if I increase the Capacity of data[] I also need to increase the time between receiving data.

EDIT: Got the whole thing working. There were more than one problems in it. Turns out that the data was being modified by what Socket.BeginReceive() method was doing internally and DataReceiver.GetChunk() that was called by me at the same time.
So now I am first receiving the data in a temporary buffer then writing it on the main buffer when the complete event is triggered while locking it so no other thread can mess with it (As far as I know, the complete method is no called in the thread in which the BeginRecieve function is invoked).

Also as @vtortola said that all data may not be in the buffer when the complete event is is triggered so I took than in consideration also.

Here is the script that actually works. It's re-written but some methods are copied from the older script (yeah I am lazy) :

```
public class DataReceiver
{
private const int DEFAULT_DIRECT_BUFFER_LIMIT = 256;
private const int DEFAULT_DATA_LIMIT = 256; // bytes

private const int HEADER_LENGTH = 2;
private const int KEYS_LENGTH = 4;

private const int SHORT_DATA = 126;
private const int SHORT_BYTES = 2;

private const int LONG_DATA = 127;
private const int LONG_BYTES = 8;

private readonly Socket TargetSocket;

private readonly object dataUpdatingLock = new object();

private bool receivingData;

private byte[] directRecieveBuffer;

private int dataReceived;
private byte[] data;

public int Capacity
{
    get
    {
        return data.Length;
    }
}

public int AmountOfDataReceived
{
    get
    {
        return dataReceived;
    }
}

public int FreeSpace
{
    get
    {
        return Capacity - AmountOfDataReceived;
    }
}

public bool ReceivingData
{
    get
    {
        return receivingData;
    }
}

public bool ChunkReady
{
    get
    {
        int chunkLength = WholeChunkLength();

        if(chunkLength < 1)
            return false;

        return chunkLength <= dataReceived;
    }
}

private DataReceiver(Socket socket, int bufferLength, int directBufferLength)
{
    this.TargetSocket = socket;
    this.data = new byte[bufferLength];
    this.directRecieveBuffer = new byte[directBufferLength];
}

public DataReceiver(Socket socket, int bufferLength) : this(socket, bufferLength, DEFAULT_DIRECT_BUFFER_LIMIT) { }

public DataReceiver(Socket socket) : this(socket, DEFAULT_DATA_LIMIT, DEFAULT_DIRECT_BUFFER_LIMIT) { }

private void ReceiveDataInternally()
{
    receivingData = true;

    int expectedDataLength = TargetSocket.Available;

    if(expectedDataLength > FreeSpace)
        expectedDataLength = FreeSpace;

    if(expectedDataLength > directRecieveBuffer.Length)
        expectedDataLength = directRecieveBuffer.Length;

    TargetSocket.BeginReceive(directRecieveBuffer, 0, expectedDataLength, SocketFlags.None, result =>
    {
        int receivedDataLength = TargetSocket.EndReceive(result);

        lock(dataUpdatingLock)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < receivedDataLength; i++)
            {
                data[dataReceived++] = directRecieveBuffer[i];
                directRecieveBuffer[i] = 0;
            }
        }

        receivingData = false;

    }, null);
}

public byte[] GetChunk()
{
    int chunkLength = WholeChunkLength();

    if(chunkLength == -1 || chunkLength > dataReceived)
        return null;

    byte[] chunk = new byte[chunkLength];

    for(int i = 0; i < chunkLength; i++)
        chunk[i] = data[i];

    lock(dataUpdatingLock)
    {
        ArrayUtilities<byte>.ShiftArrayLeft(data, chunkLength, dataReceived);
        dataReceived -= chunkLength;
    }

    return chunk;
}

private int ChunkDataLength()
{
    if(dataReceived < 1)
        return -1;

    int lengthInfoIndex = HEADER_LENGTH - 1;

    if(dataReceived < HEADER_LENGTH)
        return -1;

    int rawLength = data[lengthInfoIndex] & 127;

    int bytesRequiredToGetLength = 0;

    if(rawLength == SHORT_DATA)
        bytesRequiredToGetLength = SHORT_BYTES;
    else if(rawLength == LONG_DATA)
        bytesRequiredToGetLength = LONG_BYTES;
    else
        return rawLength;

    if(dataReceived < HEADER_LENGTH + bytesRequiredToGetLength)
        return -1;

    return Utilities.ToInt32(data, lengthInfoIndex + 1, bytesRequiredToGetLength);
}

private int WholeChunkLength()
{
    int dataLength = ChunkDataLength();
    int lengthInfoLength = dataLength < SHORT_DATA ? 0 : dataLength < short.MaxValue ? SHORT_BYTES : LONG_BYTES;

    if(dataLength == -1)
        return -1;

    return HEADER_LENGTH + lengthInfoLength + KEYS_LENGTH + dataLength;
}

public void StartReceving()
{
    if(!receivingData)
        ReceiveDataInternally();
}
}
```

Comment: You know that TCP is a stream? So multiple message can be received as one message. This happens if you send multiple messages in a short period of time. They are merged. Also a message could split up in multiple receives. `client.sendString("" + i++);` whats the length? How do you know where the next message starts?

Comment: Web sockets have a specific format each new message starts with 129 followed by the length of the actual message followed by keys and then comes the actual message. I get the length by head length byte the following (1 byte (for text frame), 1 byte (length info of the actual data), 4 bytes keys and then adding them to the length obtained to by the second byte of the buffer). I know that TCP can receive many messages as one and have made my receiver to deal with it but it still don't explain why the text frame is something abest and why keys are invalid.

Comment: I know when a new message starts by the length of the prev message.

Comment: Can you also put the code you are using to invoke that `Receiver` class? that amount of locks suggest you are doing some reckless stuff, like reading from multiple threads.

Comment: @vtortola I am (currently) calling the Receiver class only by one thread. But I surely plan to use multiple threads later in the project (I am still very easy with threading but this is a just learning project :) )..... Updated the the code in the question!

Comment: Nice. Some years ago I also did a WS server in C#, and still maintain it in time to time. It is good fun. https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener

Comment: Thanks for providing that. It will help me a lot while learning networking and web sockets :)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `recievier.ReceiveData();` , you assume the data has been read by the time that method finished but that is not right. The call to that method only initiates the read, that will end asynchronously on that anonymous delegate that calls `OnRecevingComplete`. This will be more noticeable when the app has more load that just a simple call. It would be easier if you use `TcpListener`, and work with `async/await` rather than `Socket` and the `BeginXXX` and `EndXXX` methods.

You also seems to assume that once a read has been completed, all your data is in the buffer, but it may not. For example, for reading 6 bytes, you may need to read 6 times, or 3, or maybe just 1. You need a `while` loop somewhere that keeps reading data to the buffer until you complete all the expected payload.

See the example here: [How can I read from a socket repeatedly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269291/how-can-i-read-from-a-socket-repeatedly)

```
  public void ContinuousReceive(){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    bool terminationCodeReceived = false;
    while(!terminationCodeReceived){
      try{
          if(server.Receive(buffer)>0){
             // We got something
             // Parse the received data and check if the termination code
             // is received or not
          }
      }catch (SocketException e){
          Console.WriteLine("Oops! Something bad happened:" + e.Message);
      }
    }
  }
```

As a side note:

```
return Utilities.ToInt32(Data, lengthInfoIndex + 1, bytesRequiredToGetLength);
```

`Int32` has 4 bytes, so if you parse 8 bytes as `Int32` it may overflow. Also, remember that the lengths come as `ushort`, `uint` and `ulong` (ie: unsigned integers), depending in if the header indicates <=125, 126 or 127.

You cannot read with multiple threads, and cannot write with multiple threads on a socket. You can read and write from independent ones at the same time, but not the same operation concurrently. That will lead to unpredictable errors. You should not have any lock and consider the class as not thread safe (as it is `NetworkStream` for example). Multiple threads do not lead to better performance in networking programming, just don't. Instead, focus in making your code asynchronous.

[Good old book that I loved](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0782141765,miniSiteCd-SYBEX.html).

Comment: Thanks @vtortola ! My Utilities.Int32 method handles more bytes being provided than required. I was just too lazy to provide 4 bytes as parameters but everything works and there are no overflows and it gives the right result :). You said _italic_ When you call recievier.ReceiveData(); , you assume the data has been read by the time that method finished but that is not right. _italic_ but I checked if data has been read or not by Receiver. ChunkReady property. But the problem seems to be caused because of what you said in the second paragraph. I'll re-write the class according to what you said!

Comment: OK got it working @vtortola Thanks for the help. There were many problems not just one. I have updated the questions with the working script! And as you said I have removed the locks and will only use it from one thread.